# iOS How to fetch profile image for each user use Parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have an app in which I have news, which users are added and I want in a table view to show user photo which are taken from DB "_User" and I fetch data from class "news". My code is:

```
 var user = PFUser.current()
    let useravatar = user!["profilePicture"] as? PFFile
    useravatar?.getDataInBackground{ (imageData, error)in
        if imageData != nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            cell.userPhoto.image = image
            
        }
    }
```

But this code loads only the current user photo, but I need the user photo for each row, how I can do this? Example:

[image: -]

As you see in pictures I have two user, but it loads only my profile photo.

Comment: Load image asynchronously by using DispatchQueue or Operation Queue.

Comment: Do you have example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load images asynchronously

```
var user = PFUser.current() //you'e setting an image for same user

let useravatar = user!["profilePicture"] as? PFFile
useravatar?.getDataInBackground{ (imageData, error)in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if imageData != nil, error == nil {
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        cell.userPhoto.image = image

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: are you using collection view of tableview?

Comment: No, i not use collection view

Comment: It seems that cell is repeating its content.

Comment: actually you are getting same user every time `var user = PFUser.current()` so it resulting same image.

Comment: Yes, it's because i so lazy, i copy two time one post, but to another user)

Comment: I think now issue is fixed.

Comment: But how i can load photo for each user?
Maybe i can sort by username some how

Comment: please post complete code...so that I can help you out.